# Run vbscript automatically without user permission

Tags: vbscript

Here is the code of my vb-script. Its a pretty simple one. 
 Wscript.echo “Hello World”

I want that script to run automatically without user permission when it is downloaded from website. Is that possible ?

Comment: **I hope it's not possible** or  it's not easy at least. Or would you like _any_ downloaded code runs on your computer  _without user permission_? However, you could switch off your firewall and add whole internet content to the trusted  zone...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes. It is called black hat hacking and there is a whole field of very intelligent cyber-security researchers that work to prevent this sort of thing. Even if you did find something that would run code downloaded from the internet without user permission, it would not be simple, and it would (hopefully) not work for long since it would involve exploiting a flaw in an OS's security. I won't wish you luck with your search, and I would hope that no one on SO will help you with such a project.